# NGinX config for Django and Wordpress in subdirectory

Tags: nginx, wordpress, django, php-fpm, gunicorn

I need to set up a Django site at the root of a domain, but then have a Wordpress installation in a subdirectly (e.g. /blog/). How would one configure NGinX to do this? "Pretty" URLs have to work for Wordpress as well.

For Django I am using Gunicorn, which is already configured. From NGinX I would call "proxy_pass" to direct to that. PHP is run via FPM.

Considering the restrictions above, how would I configure NGinX? Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks.

UPDATE: I've tried several things, and currently I have it working partly. I've removed any Django config. Then I've got Wordpress in a /blog/ subdirectory. In there, I have test.php, which just calls phpinfo(), and then also test.html, which shows pure html. When calling test.php, the page loads. However, when I call test.html, or index.php (Wordpress index page), it gives me a 404.

My nGinx config:

```
server {
        listen   80;

        root /path/to/www/root;

        server_name domain.com;

        access_log /path/to/logs/access.log;
        error_log /path/to/logs/error.log;

        location / {
                index index.php;
        }

        location /blog {
                alias /path/to/www/blog;
                try_files $uri =404;
                index index.php index.html;
        }

        location ~ /blog/.+\.php$ {
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /path/to/www/blog$fastcgi_script_name;
        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
location  /i/ 
{  alias  /spool/w3/images/;
}
```

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#alias

Answer (score 0):

You set up a `location /blog/` and use all the usual nginx directives to pass off to PHP.